# Document folder for previously working app using Document Browser disappeared

Tags: ios, directory, document

I have an app built that uses the UIDocumentBrowser.  It was working fine until I tried to add an ImagePickerController to allow the app to use the camera and take photos.  The Documents folder is now no where to be found on the "Files" app or in the app I am developing.  I could find it in the Finder on the Mac I am using for developing the app.

I tried deleting the entire app and data and installing a cleaned build.

I have this sitting at the top of the app launch method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    _datapath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    if (![NSFileManager.defaultManager fileExistsAtPath:_datapath])
        [NSFileManager.defaultManager createDirectoryAtPath:_datapath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

When I run it in debug, it finds the already created documents folder so skips over the createDirectoryAtPath method.

Any ideas what's happening and/or how I can fix it?

Note: I never got to the point in the app where I could test the ImagePicker before this problem happened and removing the code I added didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Must have been cached information.  Powered down the iPad and restarted fixed the problem.